# Set direction of rotation Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, swipe, direction

I am trying to make a spin wheel that is divided into 6 sections. Each section is marked with a gameObject that is centered in that section. After the player spins the wheel, it will rotate until its starts stopping and then the wheel moves and stops in the center based on the section that was selected (Randomly). I used the following code to rotate the wheel towards the 0 on X axis. this code works fine and the wheel rotates fine, but only if the selected section was on the positive X axis.

```
float rotateFloat = (((randomReward + 1) * 60) - 30) - transform.rotation.z;
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, rotateFloat));
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, f_difX * Time.deltaTime);
```

I did some digging and found that `Quaternion.RotateTowards()`finds the closest way towards the target and rotates using that direction (This caused a problem with the direction of rotation).

Example (Follow image): The player swipes and randomReward (Number 5 on spin wheel) and the wheel starts rotating. When the wheel slows down, it starts moving towards the center. Then it will stop spinning along the direction of the swipe and will rotate towards the other side (Because the distance to the center is closer from the left side).

How can I set it to follow the same direction of the swipe regardless of which is closer to the center. And maybe if there is a better way to do this, please enlighten me. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to rotate a GameObject is by using:

```
float Speed = 1f;

void Update()
{
    // Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
}
```

You can read more about his [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

It can happen sometimes the center of the GameObject it´s not placed in the center of the mesh or sprite. If you can´t modify this for any reason, what you can do is place this model/sprite as a child of an Empty GameObject and then attach the rotation script to the Empty GameObject.

Answer (score 0):

While i understand that you don't want people to rotate the disk to the reward they want. Why do you use a random reward and go through the trouble of lining the rotation to the reward?

You should be able to say catch a 'swipe time', then do some math to it (say so it turns at least once if the screen touch time is very short) and then add a random range to it, that is within the circumference of the disk. Then when the disk is done spinning do a ray cast at the top location to determine the reward? (could also link the spinning time to the swipe-time, so that the reward is offered in somewhat the same time interval).

//this comment would have been made as a comment if i would have had the rights to do so, as i think this response may help the question asker, it is provided as an answer instead. i do hope this doesn't piss any one off to much :(

Comment: This kind of what i did actually. But instead of using the 'swipe time', i used f_difX which is basically the point of where the player lefts his finger off the screen - the point where he touched the screen before swiping. I do like the idea of linking the spinning time to the swipe time. Is it possible to elaborate on that idea? or how to make a function like that? Thank you for the answer :)